# How to drop identical columns when combining data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe

How can I remove *identical* columns when combining two data frames?

Consider the dummy example below:

```
data(iris)
iris2 <- iris 
iris2[ 2:7, c(1,3,5)] <- NA
Xa <- cbind(iris, iris2)
head(Xa)
##  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
##1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
##2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa           NA         3.0           NA         0.2    <NA>
##3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa           NA         3.2           NA         0.2    <NA>
##4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa           NA         3.1           NA         0.2    <NA>
##5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa           NA         3.6           NA         0.2    <NA>
##6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa           NA         3.9           NA         0.4    <NA>
```

It is very easy to drop columns with the same name:

```
Xa <- Xa[ , !(duplicated(names(Xa)))]
head(Xa)
##  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
##1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
##2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
##3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
##4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
##5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
##6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

But not all dropped columns have the same contents. How can I drop *identical* columns (same name *and* same contents) from a data frame?

The expected result is:

```
##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species   Sepal.Length   Petal.Length   Species
## 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa            5.1            1.4    setosa
## 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa             NA             NA      <NA>
## 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa             NA             NA      <NA>
## 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa             NA             NA      <NA>
## 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa             NA             NA      <NA>
## 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa             NA             NA      <NA>
```

Comment: `Xa[!duplicated.default(Xa)]` I think is what you're after. Dunno how you'd get yourself into a situation where this is necessary, though.

Comment: @Frank Indeed. This does what I want: please consider making this an answer. (I got into similar situation when doing `dcast()` operations using several factors that have overlapping levels: one level identical across factors, while another level in one factor split in two levels in another. This generates duplicates, and---conservatively---I want do drop by content, not name.)

Comment: @Frank In fact, this situation can arise whenever you use `cbind()`, since it is merely a wrapper for `data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE)`. If the two data frames have columns with identical names (e.g. an index column), you may need to check for duplicates after the `cbind()` operation...

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that; that explains the duplicate names. (I have never had to use `cbind.data.frame`.) Regarding the factor problem you mention, I'd suggest using characters instead of factors whenever possible, starting with using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` everywhere the option is available (or setting it as a global option). I don't really understand the use-case/problem in either this or the `dcast` case you mention. Surely, your "expected result" here is not something you can use for analysis, so this must be some sort of data cleaning step...

Comment: @Frank Yes, this is indeed a data cleaning step (after `dcast()` or `ddply()` operations, and when merging with main data frame). As for characters vs factors, I started out with characters but slowly got converted to use factors instead (not least for controlling reference level in regressions and avoid "converted to factor" warnings). Why do you suggest characters are preferable?

Comment: I think factors are only useful when calling regression functions or the `table` function. It's easy enough to convert to factor when needed. During data manipulation, factors simply get in the way, with their mess of levels and labels that interfere with normal operations. More times than I can count, folks on SO (including me) have been confused by the fact that factors magically become integers in many (but not all) contexts, for example.

Comment: @Frank Yeah, I see your point. Good point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```
Xa[!duplicated.default(Xa)]
# or
Xa[, !duplicated.default(Xa)]
# or, as mentioned by @akrun in a comment
Xa[!duplicated(c(Xa))]
```

Whichever way, the columns are renamed automatically (as `data.frame()` usually does) so that there are no longer any dupes among them.

We can't use vanilla `duplicated` here because it would use `duplicated.data.frame`, which compares rows to find duplicates, while `duplicated.default` compares elements of a vector. A data.frame is an vector of (pointers to) column vectors, so that's why `duplicated.default` works in this case. `duplicated(c(Xa))` or `duplicated(as.list(Xa))` also work because they change `Xa` from a data.frame into a vanilla vector.

Comment: I'm curious why we need to force `duplicated.default()` or  coerce the `data.frame` to a `list` instead of using the `duplicated.data.frame()` method?

Comment: @landroni `duplicated.data.frame` compares rows to find duplicates, while `duplicated.default` compares elements of a vector. A data.frame is an vector of (pointers to) column vectors, so that's why `duplicated.default` works in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Based on  the accepted answer, I came up with a very simple function for this task:

```
rm.df.dupl <- function(x){
    stopifnot(is.data.frame(x))
    x <- x[ , !duplicated.default(x)]
    return(x)
}
```

All you have to do now is:

```
rm.df.dupl(Xa)
```